# Output to multiple files with Makefile

Tags: make

I have a makefile that I use to convert files in markdown into .pdf through a latex template. At the moment, this only works with one file at a time. However, I'd like the makefile to run on *any* markdown file in the active directory and output to a .pdf with the same name with a single make command. For example, I might have the following:

Foo.md ---> Foo.pdf

Bar.md ---> Bar.pdf

My current makefile is here:

```
TEX = pandoc
MEXT = md
src = template.tex $(wildcard *.$(MEXT))
FLAGS = --latex-engine=xelatex

letter.pdf : $(src)
$(TEX) $(filter-out $<,$^ ) -o $@ --template=$< $(FLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean :
rm output.pdf
```

Thank you for any pointers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# List files to be made by finding all *.md files and appending .pdf

PDFS := $(patsubst %.md,%.md.pdf,$(wildcard *.md))

# The all rule makes all the PDF files listed
all : $(PDFS)

# This generic rule accepts PDF targets with corresponding Markdown 
# source, and makes them using pandoc
%.md.pdf : %.md
    pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex $< -o $@

# Remove all PDF outputs
clean :
    rm $(PDFS)

# Remove all PDF outputs then build them again
rebuild : clean all
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
TEX = pandoc
MEXT = md
SRC = $(wildcard *.$(MEXT))
PDFS = $(SRC:.md=.pdf)
TMP = template.tex
FLAGS = --latex-engine=xelatex

all:    ${PDFS}

%.pdf:  %.md ${TMP}
        ${TEX} $(filter-out $<,$^ ) -o $@ --template=${TMP} $(FLAGS) $<


.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm *.pdf
```

Comment: Getting "missing separator" error from the makefile...what causes that?

Comment: @LarryTate Replace the 8-spaces indents by a tab.

Comment: Which lines need the tab? I've tried each line but I get the error. Sorry!

Comment: All indentation should be tabs.

Comment: OK, I tried changing my text to use tabs, but SO converts to spaces so you wouldn't be able to copy/paste anyway. I'm afraid you'll just have to convert manually.

Comment: By the way, SO uses 4-column tabs, which is why all the indentation in your original post got lost.

Comment: your `clean` target could match the `all` target and `rm -f ${PDFS}`.

Comment: Meta: pipe text through `unexpand -a` and your spaces will be converted to tabs for you.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test this completely but I think it should work with some modification. Using for loop:

```
TEX = pandoc
MEXT = md
SRC = $(wildcard *.$(MEXT))
TMP = template.tex
FLAGS = --latex-engine=xelatex

letter.pdf : 
    $(foreach i, $(SRC), $(TEX) -o $(i).pdf --template=$(TMP) $(FLAGS) $(i);)

.PHONY: clean
clean :
    rm -f *.pdf
```

Also note that this solution will not produce `pdf` files with exactly the same name as `md` files:

```
foo.md -> foo.md.pdf
```

Should not be hard to fix though.